Chatgpt base64 encoded image
I’m trying to pass a base64 encoded image to gpt-4o, but gets an 400 Invalid base64 image_url.
I use the following code:
const openairesponse = await openai.chat.completions.create({
model: "gpt-4o",
messages: [
  { role: 'system', content: "Convert the image to text" },
  {
  "role": "user",
  "content": [
    {
    "type": "image_url",
    "image_url": {
      //The base64 encoded image
      "url": "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+base64Image
    }
    }
  ]
  }
],
});

The base64Image is s string starting with ‘/9j/’ and should be valid.
But openai returns invalid image url.
Any idea on how to resolve this?

are you sure the image is a jpeg?

Probably related: https://community.openai.com/t/how-to-send-base64-images-to-assistant-api/752440

also, looks like they expect an actual image URL; so a base64 image would not work in that field

I'm sure the image is jpeg. I have followed the guide from the official documentation, which includes an url field, even though it's a base64 encoded image (also think it sounds weird): https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/vision?lang=curl
